# What happens when I dont use reactive Quarkus extensions?

Tags: java, quarkus, vert.x, quarkus-reactive

if I dont use the reactive extensions for Quarkus Is the I/O op going to be non-blocking or blocking? I am asking this because I didnt like the reactive programming style, I wish I could have something like c# async await for java

Comment: i ask myself the same thing. I want to start a quarkus-project in my mid-sized company, and i want to see quarkus stating in their docs that it is totally fine to stay with react-classic, and that they are not replacing it sometimes in the future. It is also not really convincing that reactive is always the best (its hard to debug, it increases code complexity). Managing your servers with a fixed number of threads makes it easy to replicate them in the cloud when they reach their limit. It may have benefits for large companies that can get benefits out of the reactive-style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that Quarkus is reactive under the hood, does **not** force users to do any reactive programming.

Users are free (and in most cases encouraged) to use regular blocking APIs. When that is done, Quarkus will delegate the work to worker threads.

Some details can be found [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/quarkus-reactive-architecture).

Comment: would you mind to add any material explaining how that works?

Comment: I added a link to my answer

Comment: there are also cases where quarkus discourages users to use regular blocking APIs. For example. Read the chapter "Being reactive" in following link:
- https://quarkus.io/continuum/

while quarkus does not force users to do any reactive programming, it gives them the impression, that they should migrate to reactive, and dont make it clear that they will always support the non-reactive style (just my impression)